# Keep my process alive - always

Tags: c++, windows, process

Is it possible to stop users (even admin) from killing my program?
or in case of killing, it restores itself quickly?

**UPDATE:**
to clarify: I'm writing a monitoring program, something like parental control which keeps record of what a user do with PC. you can guess that by viewing my other questions recently.
The first need of such a program is being alive!

now, anyone help?

Comment: Ask your virus-writing pals, they have a lot of such tricks up their sleeves.

Comment: are you writing malware?

Comment: It's possible to make it very hard to kill. This is a bad idea.

Comment: Would you like my social security number, too?

Comment: If your program displays a nice message like "Please don't kill me. I am not a virus" or something that just might do the trick

Comment: I understand this question seems a bit strange, but I don't see any reason to close it. Especially as "Not a real question", since the question is there and to the point.

Comment: Short answer is: Yes. But the interesting question is: Why would one need that?

Comment: @MBZ:  With your clarification, I give you +1 for a good question.  But I also give you a -1 for a snotty attitude and a sense of entitlement.

Comment: tnx John, I'll rephrase the Update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, don't do that. Second, still don't do that.

Third, if your program is sooooo awesome that it should never stop running you could always provide the capability to install a service that runs your program and restarts it if it dies. But think long and hard about that because users typically get pretty annoyed about programs that won't die. Instead make your program useful enough that no one will WANT it to stop running, and restart it if it dies.

EDIT: OK so given your update to the OP let's try a few thoughts here.

There are two basic cases to consider: If the end user has admin rights on the machine there's pretty much nothing you can do in the general case. Whatever you attempt can be bypassed by someone with administrative privileges.

So then what if the user doesn't have admin rights. Then users can't kill arbitrary processes started by root/administrator. In that case you can try to install your software as a daemon style/always running. On Windows you would install as a system service that autostarts on boot. For Solaris you would use SMF and set it to auto-restart on termination. On Linux you could do something like a root-owned shell that loops forever restarting the program if it exits.

Comment: Consider a nanny application.  The parents want it to stay running so that Junior doesn't download porn, and yet Junior wants to kill it in order to download porn.  Family values and parenting advice aside, not all awesome programs are going to be kept running when they should.

Comment: tnx for example and answer. btw there is another scenario. there are lots of home PCs with windows on them and everyone uses a prebuilt admin user on them. what about them?

Comment: @MBZ If the users you're trying to restrict are already administrators the battle is already lost: There's nothing you can do. Obfuscation may stop a small portion of them but the rest will happily disable your software. Obviously this can be solved by making users login on non-admin accounts.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Admin always knows how to chop off power supply.

*Ok, now that clarification is here, I'll add some words as well.*

I've actually seen a parental control tool for Windows that used several instances of the same process monitoring each other and that would restart their complices immediately if the user terminated one of them. Worked quite well - unless somebody would switch to the console and kill them quick enough. However, using Task Manager was far to slow.

Of course the approach is limited, especially since the administrator could easily remove the autostart entries (which could be avoided i.e. by using a somewhat hidden service to spawn the processes). Still, unless you target extremely hacker-ish children, it is quite effective.

But after all, people could just reinstall their complete OS, thus avoiding all precautions you may take. *So the best way is probably to hide your tool and hope that it won't be found.*

Answer (score 0):

you might be insane. It is ALWAYS possible to kill or destroy a "Naive" annoying program. try something good.